# Как из саги вызвать ту же сагу, с теми же аргументами

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

Есть сага, в которой есть блоки `try/catch`, в саге делается некая логика, включающая запрос на сервер. Если статус-код из ответа равен 401, что соответствует истекшему токену, то обработка этой ошибки переходит в блок `catch`. В этом блоке выполняется запрос для получения нового токена и из ответа получается сам токен, который заменяет истекший. Но проблема в том, что мне необходимо возобновить ту логику, которая была в блоке `try` с теми же данными, которые и пришли в в сагу, сразу же в блоке `catch` после замены токена. Т.е. у меня есть сага, которая получает какие-то данные. При получении 401 статус кода обработка переходит в блок `catch`, где по сути сага должна вызваться заново с теми же данными. Как организовать данную рекурсию?

Comment: В документации саги есть описание таких случаев - https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/recipes/#retrying-xhr-calls

Answer (score 0):

Не сразу подумал, что можно просто задиспатчить тот же экшен с теми же данными в блоке `catch` через `yield put` после обновления токена.